# Accesar a app en nodejs desde internet

Tags: nodejs

Acabo de realizar una app con nodejs y arduino usando Johnny-Five. De forma local funciona perfecto y acceso a ella desde cualquier dispositivo que esté en la misma red local. Lo que quiero ahora es accesar a mi app pero desde internet, es decir, en lugar de localhost:3000, que sea por ejemplo "miapp.com" ¿Cual es la mejor manera para hacer eso? Intenté con noip pero la ip pública que maneja mi proveedor de internet es inaccesible desde otro lado.

Comment: Tal vez [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com) sea lo que buscas. Saludos

Comment: Excelente opción!

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente deberías configurar en el router o modem que tengas eso, abrir el puerto para tu app, luego por la ip publica del arduino podrás acceder desde afuera, también si quieres agregarlo a un dominio, debes habilitar y apuntar el dominio a tu servidor por dns.